# call function to each cell in a range (involve insert rows, so the range will change) in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning VBA and have some problems

What I have is a list of date:
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOal4.png)

What I want to do is add 3 meals for everyday like this
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCYei.png)

I have recorded a macro which can achieve this:

```
Sub InsertMeal()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Breakfast"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lunch"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dinner"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -2).Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.Merge
End Sub
```

Now I want write a macro, which apply this InsertMeal() function to each cells in selected range.

This is what I wrote

```
Sub ApplyToAll()
    For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells
        Call InsertMeal
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is, since I insert rows every time, the For loop doesn't work well. The loop never end. Now I don't know how to "keep the range" to make the loop work.

Please help if you know how to do this. Thank you, really appreciate.

Comment: Unrelated but you have`InsertMeal` then `InsertTime`? Edit: why not just use loop within `InsertMeal`?

Comment: sorry I change the 1st function name, but forgot to change the 2nd when I pasted into stackoverflow. Just consider the 2 are the same please.

Comment: No comment on the second question? If there's no reason, don't call another sub, just loop in the original sub.

Comment: but it still won't end the loop. I think it's because the `ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells` always change?

Comment: Please edit OP/don't put code in comments. Edit: yea you want a better loop such as `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no need for two functions here. To amend your loop to do what you need, b/c you are adding rows, you will need to nest a small loop inside the other loop that works in you block of `3` ,`Breakfast` ,`Lunch`, and `Dinner`.

The code would look something like this, but you will have to amend the range to suit your purpose. For example

```
Sub dave()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim j As Long

   lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row * 3
   x = Array("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner")

  For i = 1 To lastrow
     Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
     For j = 1 To 3
       Cells(i + j - 1, 3).Value = x(j - 1)
     Next j
       Cells(i, 1).Resize(3).Merge: i = i + 2
  Next i
End Sub
```

BTW, the lastrow will need to be multiplied by 3 as you are addeding rows, so the original lastrow will not reflect the actuall last row when finnished.

Comment: It works perfect! You inspired me a lot! Thank you KyloRen. Now I know how to use things like `End(xlUp)`,`Resize()`,etc. I also improved your codes so that it can be applied to any selected region. Feel free to leave a comment :D

Comment: Another way is to work backwards from last row to first - `For i = lastrow to 1 Step -1`.  Inserting rows won't affect the loop then.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RelativeFunc()
    col = ActiveCell.Column
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    firstrow = Cells(1, col).End(xlDown).Row
    rownum = lastrow - firstrow + 1
    frownum = rownum * 3

    x = Array("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner")

    For i = 1 To frownum
        Cells(i + firstrow, col).Resize(2).EntireRow.Insert
        For j = 1 To 3
            Cells(firstrow + i - 1 + j - 1, col + 1).Value = x(j - 1)
        Next j
        Cells(firstrow + i - 1, col).Resize(3).Merge
        i = i + 2
    Next i
End Sub
```